# Removing a contact from "Frequently contacted" on Hangout (formerly Google Talk) app

Tags: google-talk

After the recent update to v.1.0.1.678536 on my Nexus S, I see that it is automatically listing few contacts as "frequently contacted", I don't want to see certain people on that list, and there is no way to remove someone from the "Frequently contacted" list through mobile UI.

I have tried the following:
1) From the Web UI, I have set that contact to "Never Show"
2) I blocked that contact from the Web UI

None of these seems to work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Long press on the contacts name when using hangouts from your phone. you will then have the option to hide the contact.  The contact will then no longer show up in your frequently contacted list. If it is a contact that you don't want in your hangouts list at all, go to your gmail account and delete them that way.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I already tried the long press but I thought it was going to hide it from contact list not only from the frequent list. That message is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple of undesirable contacts, on my frequently contacted list, on Hangouts as well.  I was signed into my account and went to contacts.google.com

On the left side, there is a "Most Contacted" option that you need to click on (It is underneath "Circles").  From there it will show you a list of people that you have contacted most frequently.  When I deleted the offending contacts, they were removed from Hangouts.

I have a Nexus 7 so hopefully these tips will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I deleted the contact, but it still kept showing up..I moved that person from "Friends" circle to something else and after a day or so, it went away on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Frequently contacted is simply displaying what it interprets as 'most contacted' it is NOT a separate list that you can delete... If you delete these they WILL be deleted from your main contacts!! Beware!

Answer (score 1):

In your contacts, check if the star near the three dots is dark. If so, tap on it and that contact should disappear from your frequently contacted.